# Google Cloud Storage: How Much Total Space Am I Using?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, dashboard, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I am using Google Cloud Storage. Where can I determine my total space used? I can't seem to find where in the dashboard it tells you the total usage in megabytes or gigabytes.

[image: Screenshot of Dashboard]

Answer (score 9):

As explained in [du - Display object size usage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/du) we coul use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) command

```
gsutil -o GSUtil:default_project_id=[PROJECT-ID] du -shc
```

It will show all space of each of the buckets and total space used like this

```
24.18 MiB    gs://appspot.[PROJECT-ID].com
687.46 MiB   gs://artifacts.[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com
947 B        gs://[PROJECT-ID]_cloudbuild
252.55 MiB   gs://staging.[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com
9.36 GiB     gs://us.artifacts.[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com
10.3 GiB     total
```

Note if you get `"ImportError: No module named google_compute_engine"` please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7940). Can be solved by running `export BOTO_CONFIG=/dev/null` before running `gsutil`.

Answer (score 8):

Do you have the `gsutil` command line utility installed?  If so, you can use the `gsutil du` command to see the space used for objects and buckets.

E.g., `gsutil du -s gs://my-bucket-name/` should work.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/du

Comment: Eeks... there's no way to see it in a dashboard? Would be nice if non-programmers could see how much space we're using.

Comment: @speedplane – thanks for the feedback, I passed it on to the team. In the mean time, you can also click on the [Google Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-shell/#how_do_i_get_started) button in the console to run the command, so you don't have to install `gcloud` locally.

Comment: It would be really useful to be able to see the amount of space being used on the dashboard - I was a bit surprised it wasn't possible to add it to the dashboard already

Comment: This is not practical for large buckets. The other answer, though it takes more steps, is more useful for buckets with a lot of files.

Comment: The ability to see the total storage in the dashboard is still missing.

Answer (score 8):

What you need is now available through Stackdriver Metrics Explorer, go to Stackdriver -> Resources -> Metrics Explorer -> under the Find resource type and metric entry field choose "Total bytes" or enter "storage.googleapis.com/storage/total_bytes" and click on the one that shows up. It'll then show you usage for all buckets in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this information through the API, like in this python example:

```py
import os
from google.cloud import storage

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "/path/to/my/credentials.json"
bucket_name = "my-bucket-name"
storage_client = storage.Client()
bytes_used = sum(
    [blob.size for blob in storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)]
)
print(
    f"{bucket_name} is using {bytes_used/1048576:0.3f} MiB."
)
```